# Add alertview in application when you recive push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

Hi Im currently developing an app where i have push notifications activated. I use parse.com. I have got it working so far that i can send a notification and the device receives it and i also get a badge on the app. But when i open the nothing happens and the badge does not disappear. I've set it in my appdelegate.m so parse is handling the push notifications. Heres some code that im using:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

and also:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

Thanks

Ok thaks but how to i show the content of the push notification in the alert view? Or is that not a problem do i just have to configure a alertview with no text?

Answer (score 2):

There are two scenarios:

### App closed

When the app is closed and the user taps on a notification it's like when taps on the app icon. The app starts from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. To know if the app is opened normal (tap icon) or with a notification, just check the dictionary `launchOptions` for the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        NSDictionary * pushDictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

        if (pushDictionary)
        {
            //AlertView
        }
}
```

### App opened

When the app is opened there are two possible case

App in background `UIApplicationStateInactive`

App in foreground `UIApplicationStateActive`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
        {
            //AlertView
        }
        else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
        {
            // AlertView
        }
}
```

`pushDictionary` and `userInfo` are exactly the same dictionary that represents the notification.

**Edit 1**

A push notification is a JSON file that iOS automatically convert into a `NSDictionary`. The standard configuration is:

```
{"aps":
 {
   "alert":"Text message",
   "sound":"default",
   "badge":"1" //the number shown on the app's icon
 }
}
```

From this base you can extend the JSON and put inside your own content. For example

```
{"aps":
  {
    "alert":"Text message",
    "sound":"default",
    "badge":"1" //the number shown on the app's icon
  },
 "Name":"Fry"
}
```

Now you can retrive the name in this very simple way:

```
NSString * name = userInfo[@"Name"];
```

and show it in the alert.

**Edit 2**

To show the content of push in `UIAlertView` just do this:

```
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:name
                                                 message:name
                                                delegate:self 
                                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [av show];
```

Comment: Ok thaks but how to i show the content of the push notification in the alert view? Or is that not a problem do i just have to configure a alertview with no text?

Comment: Hi I got it working now so thanks for that but i wonder one thing tho, in my UIAlertView i have a message that contains of "%@". So the push notification is displayed in the message, but what i want to do is the same thing but with the title. Is that possible?.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive push notification while your app isn't active (killed)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

will not be triggered. Instead of that you will have to use object with key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` from `launchOptions` dictionary inside

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Comment: Ok thaks but how to i show the content of the push notification in the alert view? Or is that not a problem do i just have to configure a alertview with no text?